# Sort fans of a facebook page by join date

Tags: facebook

I can't seem to find a way to find out the chronological order specific users 'liked' a page. The main purpose would be to award lets say the 5000th user that joined "my" page. However, as much data as possible is also beneficial - be it acquired via standard means (via facebook site), or the facebook API (which I currently know nothing about).

*P.S. I hope I'm asking this on the right page, if it should be moved to one of the stack exchange sites, let me know or just do so.*

Comment: IMO users are displayed in this manner in list on Fanpage. Users who join first are on the bottom.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking this question then. No, they are not.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API solution for this, and the fan list isn't ordered chronologically on the site. This is by design.